# addResults options doesn't work in bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-select

I would like to use `addResults` option in [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/blob/master/docs/docs/options.md) to add new items. I should be prompted to add search string, but I get default message `No Results`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86agkpkb/)

**component.jsx**

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $(this.selectPicker).selectpicker({
      liveSearch: true,
      addResults: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select className="form-control" data-width="100%" ref={el => (this.selectPicker = el)}>
                    <optgroup label="Group 1">
                      <option defaultValue>Team</option>
                      <option value="1">AAA</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Group 2">
                      <option value="2">BAC</option>
                      <option value="3">BAY</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Group 3">
                      <option value="4">DACA</option>
                    </optgroup>
                  </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: What if you have the same code in `componentDidUpdate` as in `componentDidMount`? Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/86agkpkb/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is the same.

Comment: This is not an issue with react but seems to be an issue with bootstrap-select. I've [added an issue](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1975) but seeing the amount of issues open I don't think that is going to do much good.

Comment: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/pull/1403 Looks like this was only recently added. For whatever reason, there is literally no logic for this feature in the code. I would be hopeful that they can fix it quickly since it's not some bug in the logic but rather missing code that got lost somewhere in the PR.